# RollingFileManager checkRollover runs into thread contention

Tags: logging, log4j, log4j2

I saw a similar issue on [LOG4J2-953](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4J2-953) which got closed without a clear resolution. Is this fixed in later versions or is async logger the resolution for this

```
"app[8cb2010de1b58d5b][TG][T#1]" #28 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 cpu=72688.46ms elapsed=7965.70s tid=0x00007fdaeb094800 nid=0x52d waiting for monitor entry  [0x00007fdaa43ff000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object monitor)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.rolling.RollingFileManager.checkRollover(RollingFileManager.java:217)
    - waiting to lock <0x000000102a7aec48> (a org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.rolling.RollingFileManager)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.RollingFileAppender.append(RollingFileAppender.java:267)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppenderControl.tryCallAppender(AppenderControl.java:156)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppenderControl.callAppender0(AppenderControl.java:129)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppenderControl.callAppenderPreventRecursion(AppenderControl.java:120)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppenderControl.callAppender(AppenderControl.java:84)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggerConfig.callAppenders(LoggerConfig.java:448)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggerConfig.processLogEvent(LoggerConfig.java:433)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggerConfig.log(LoggerConfig.java:417)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggerConfig.logParent(LoggerConfig.java:439)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggerConfig.processLogEvent(LoggerConfig.java:434)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggerConfig.log(LoggerConfig.java:417)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggerConfig.log(LoggerConfig.java:403)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AwaitCompletionReliabilityStrategy.log(AwaitCompletionReliabilityStrategy.java:63)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.Logger.logMessage(Logger.java:146)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.ExtendedLoggerWrapper.logMessage(ExtendedLoggerWrapper.java:217)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLogger.tryLogMessage(AbstractLogger.java:2170)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLogger.logMessageTrackRecursion(AbstractLogger.java:2125)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLogger.logMessageSafely(AbstractLogger.java:2108)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLogger.logIfEnabled(AbstractLogger.java:1827)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLogger.debug(AbstractLogger.java:293)
```

Answer (score 0):

I created the issue and closed it after I determined the behavior was correct. If you have a similar issue I would suggest you report it in the Log4j Jira system with sufficient information to diagnose the issue.